# Best practice for checking remote commands

Tags: java, remote-server

I'm building an application that runs all kind of commands on remote servers (linux & unix) and get their status, usually the command will run between few minutes to a day. I want to understand which approach for that is better.

Stay connected to the server until the command is done OR to connect to the server every X seconds/minutes/hours and check the status of the job.

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you try to stay connected, network failures happen, especially over long running connections (and you hit various timeouts, etc, etc).  this means you generally end up having to handle reconnects anyway.  unless you need immediate feedback, i would go with periodic polling.